# Choosing a movement strategy based on the type of chess piece

Tags: java, chess

`PawnMovement` ... `KingMovement` are of type `Movement`. This is implementation of strategy pattern. Basing on actual value of `PieceType` I want to choose proper strategy. How to avoid long if/else statements or switch?

```
    PieceType pieceType;
    if(this.board.getPieceAt(from) != null) {
        pieceType = this.board.getPieceAt(from).getType();
    } else {
        throw new InvalidMoveException();
    }

    if (pieceType == PieceType.PAWN) {
        contextMovement.setContext(new PawnMovement());
    } else if (pieceType == PieceType.ROOK) {
        contextMovement.setContext(new RookMovement());
    } else if (pieceType == PieceType.KNIGHT) {
        contextMovement.setContext(new KnightMovement());
    } else if (pieceType == PieceType.BISHOP) {
        contextMovement.setContext(new BishopMovement());
    } else if (pieceType == PieceType.QUEEN) {
        contextMovement.setContext(new QueenMovement());
    } else if (pieceType == PieceType.KING) {
        contextMovement.setContext(new KingMovement());
    }
    return contextMovement.executeMovement(from, to, board);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity of approach is too high, it can be reduced to the following:

```
PieceType pieceType = getPieceType();
contextMovement.setContext(pieceType.getMovement());
return contextMovement.executeMovement(from, to, board);
```

The `PieceType` enum (probably call it `Piece`?) can be extended with:

```
public enum Piece {

  PAWN() {
    @Override
    public Movement getMovement() { 
      return new PawnMovement();
    }
  }, ... // other elements;

  public abstract Movement getMovement();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the information carried by `PieceType` is tightly coupled to the possible movement. This is not due to your coding, it's due to the modelled domain.

In a somewhat common case I came with a solution that reflects the coupling of domain artifacts in code. I hooked up the functionality to the enum:

```
enum Strategy {
    SQUARE() {
        public int perform(int arg) {
            return arg * arg;
        }
    },
    TRIPLE() {
        public int perform(int arg) {
            return 3 * arg;
        }
    };
    abstract public int perform(int arg);
}
```

Elsewhere in your code you just hand the instrumented enum value around and all functionality is at hand.

```
int performWith(Strategy s, int i) {
    ...
    return s.perform(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Have each piece implement the type of movement it makes. This means each piece inherits from `Movement` class so you can just call something like `piece.getMovementContext()`
- Store the movement for each piece in an `EnumMap` and do a look up of the movement depending on the piece.